Split uppercase from Title
I have a string like this:
'ARCADI, G.; DORSCH, G. C.; NETO, J. P.; QUEIROZ, F. S.; OVIEDO-TORRES, Y. M. Probing a dark sector with collider physics, direct detection, and gravitational waves. Physics Letters, Section B: Nuclear, Elementary Particle and High-Energy Physics, v. 848, Jan. 2024.'
And I want to split it in:
['ARCADI, G.', 'DORSCH, G. C.', 'NETO, J. P.', 'QUEIROZ, F. S.', 'OVIEDO-TORRES, Y. M.']
using python.
Can someone help me?
The first authors are easy to get using split(';') but I don't know how to get the last one.

You could probably do it using regex: re.findall(r"[A-Z]+, [A-Z]\.( ?[A-Z]\.)?", my_string)

You could look into regular expressions but you'll need to figure out how exactly the last author name is separated from the title. If names are always upper case, you could look for the first mixed-case word, but you'd also consider the "A" in "A study in scarlet" to be part of the author initials. Maybe look for upper case letter followed by a dot.

The author names appear to be in all caps.  So you could find the first lowercase letter, then find the location of the nearest preceding space, and split that substring on semicolons.

an hardcoded way: s.partition(' Probing')[0].split('; ')

One possible solution is to remove the string you don't want and then split:
import re

s = "ARCADI, G.; DORSCH, G. C.; NETO, J. P.; QUEIROZ, F. S.; OVIEDO-TORRES, Y. M. Probing a dark sector with collider physics, direct detection, and gravitational waves. Physics Letters, Section B: Nuclear, Elementary Particle and High-Energy Physics, v. 848, Jan. 2024."

out = re.sub(r"\s[A-Z][a-z].*", "", s).split("; ")
print(out)

Prints:
['ARCADI, G.', 'DORSCH, G. C.', 'NETO, J. P.', 'QUEIROZ, F. S.', 'OVIEDO-TORRES, Y. M.']


Andrej Kesely, thank you very much. This work like a charm. I'm going to look for a tutorial into regular expressions to learn more.

You can use a pattern r'[A-Z]+[^\r\n;]*?(?:\b[A-Z]\.\s*)+':
import re
def _ut(s):
    p = r'[A-Z]+[^\r\n;]*?(?:\b[A-Z]\.\s*)+'
    f = [subs.strip() for subs in re.findall(p, s)]
    return f
s = 'ARCADI, G.; DORSCH, G. C.; NETO, J. P.; QUEIROZ, F. S.; OVIEDO-TORRES, Y. M. Probing a dark sector with collider physics, direct detection, and gravitational waves.'
print(_ut(s))


Prints
['ARCADI, G.', 'DORSCH, G. C.', 'NETO, J. P.', 'QUEIROZ, F. S.', 'OVIEDO-TORRES, Y. M.']

